# LSTM in Tensorflow: to Keras or not to Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, theano, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I will be using recurrent networks in my future work, for example, predicting a particular stock price from a wide range of time dependent indicators (features). Would it be better to go directly to Tensorflow instead of having it wrapped up in Keras? The wrapping makes things easier, but it seems to obscure the underlining structures, remove some control from the users, and degrade the performance. If both Keras and Tensorflow are poorly documented, would it still be worth while to go through a layer of wrapping? This applies not only to Keras, but also to tflearn, or anything else for that matter, given that there is a tendency for software engineers to look for projects in writing wrappers of dubious value.

I haven't run Tensorflow LSTM directly yet. A quick test with Keras on Windows 10 got totally unacceptable run time. Also, it does't seem to have a way of setting the results to be deterministic.

I am not considering Theano at this point due to limited bandwidth.

Thanks!

Comment: Completely depends on what exactly is your future work. In my opinion, unless a specific use-case is not determined, a framework decision cannot be performed.

Comment: I agree with @phoxis. The only thing I might add is in my personal experience Keras has been flexible enough for all my needs. I have not, so far, had to go directly to tensorflow. Keras has an exposed "Backend" module that basically implements a lot of tensorflow and functions which gives you a lot of flexibility. This question is going to be mostly opinion based.

Comment: Because it is opinion based, you might like it to be a more specific. Else it may be voted to be closed.

Comment: Again, this question is opinion based, but I would go with Keras. I have not found it limiting even with very customized model creations and such. I find it a much nicer logical approach than tf. I also quite like pytorch